# How to redirect different pages in one iframe of same page while clicking on different menu items in jsp?

Tags: jsp, iframe

Now I am doing jsp page. There is vertical menu and one iframe. I have to display respective page in  iframe after clicking the respective menu item. I can't use frameset because of some limitations of frameset. How can I do it? Please can u give me code for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use given codes.

```
<iframe src="default.html" name="myframe">
<p>Supported</p>
</iframe>
<ul>
<li><a href="page1.html" target="myframe">Page1</a></li>
<li><a href="page2.html" target="myframe">Page2</a></li>
<li><a href="page3.html" target="myframe">Page3</a></li>
<li><a href="page4.html" target="myframe">Page4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Learn more about [Iframe name attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_name.asp)